How can I make my flex-grow layout mobile friendly
I wrote this block https://www.codeply.com/p/6jbL7Wl3K2 that works perfect for my purpose. A fix-height top bar, and fix-height bottom bar, the middle parts (left and right) are filling the remaining space.
However, I am struggling to make it mobile/small-screen friendly. I want to make the orignal left and right to be vertical now, with a fixed 400px height. I tried to use various media queries, but all have issues.
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
<div class='bg-blue-700 px-8 flex items-center justify-between py-4 text-white'> Top </div>
<div class='relative flex flex-grow'>
    <nav class='bg-white w-1/2'> Left </nav>
    <main class='bg-gray-100 flex-1'> Right </main>
</div>
<div class='h-20 bg-red-200'> </div>

https://www.codeply.com/p/6jbL7Wl3K2



Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

Where md is the example breakpoint between larger viewport and smaller viewport view:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
<div class='bg-blue-700 px-8 flex items-center justify-between py-4 text-white'> Top </div>
<div class='relative md:flex flex-grow'>
    <nav class='bg-white md:w-1/2 max-md:h-[400px]'> Left </nav>
    <main class='bg-gray-100 flex-1 max-md:h-[400px]'> Right </main>
</div>
<div class='h-20 bg-red-200'> </div>




The horizontal layout is limited to md and larger via the md:flex class.
We set the fixed 400px height via the max-md:h-[400px]. The max-md: limits the CSS rule application to only up to md.

